# How to “draw a search” on maps?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, maps, mobile-application

I would like to understand the tools and technologies used to implement "draw a search" on apps like Redfin, Zillow, etc. For those who are not familiar with the application's functionality, it allows users to interact with the map and draw a free-form polygon. An elastic search is then performed to display real estate listings limited to the selected area.

Comment: Kibana uses https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw to implement drawing search areas